# Private keyword and virtual function access

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and trying to understand how `private`, `protected` and `public` modifiers affect bindings.

I wrote this code:

```
public class A {

    public void a() {
        System.out.println("a in A.");
        b();
    }

    private void b() {
        System.out.println("b in A.");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B obj = new B();
        obj.a();
    }
} 

class B extends A {
    public void b() {
        System.out.println("b in B.");
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
a in A.
b in A.
```

Still, `B` has it's own `b` method, and `obj` is `B`'s instance. Why the output isn't the following?

```
a in A.
b in B.
```

But if I change `b` method in `A` to the following:

```
public void b() {
    System.out.println("b in A.");
}
```

the output changes to the expected:

```
a in A.
b in B.
```

So, why doesn't `b` behave like virtual function when it's declared with `private` keyword in `A`?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen In the very first code snippet.

Comment: Yeah my mistake, I read through it twice and *still* missed private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because private methods (and fields) are invisible outside of the class, including to subclasses. So a private method is not part of the outside interface and cannot be overridden.

That class B declares a method of the same name with the same signature does not matter. The private method is completely invisible to B, so it might as well have a different name. The two methods have no relationship at all.

When you make the method `public` (or `protected`) it becomes part of the class' API and can be overridden.

It is good practice (and an IDE will do that automatically for you) to annotate all methods that you think override something with `@Override`. Then the compiler will tell you if it does not (you would have gotten a compile error with this example), so this helps to catch spelling mistakes, mismatched signatures and stuff.

Comment: But `obj` is an instance of `B`. So shouldn't `b()` call `b` declared in `B`? Why does it call `b` declared in `A`?

Comment: the call to `b()` is in `a()`, which is defined in class A (which knows that it is calling a private method, which cannot be overridden). If you put the same code in class B, it would in fact, call B's method. Same source code does not always have the same effect. Again, *private methods cannot be overridden* (are "not virtual").

Comment: I got it. Thanks! So when the compiler sees that the method is private, it just substitutes it in all the functions in the same class to avoid overhead connected with dynamic method resolution. Correct?!

Comment: I don't know about "substitute", but yes, dynamic method resolution does not take place.

Answer (score 1):

That is because as per [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/names.html#104285),

> A private class member or constructor is accessible only within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor. It is not inherited by subclasses.

So the above answer your question. 
But had the case been there for protected or public, then this is valid:

```
class Ex{
   protected void a()
   {        
   }
} 


 class Child extends Ex{
    @Override
    public void a()
    {

    }
 }
`
```

Comment: Yeah. But I may define another method with the same name in the subclass. And if the object is the instance of the *subclass*, then it's not very clear that this method will be used not from the subclass (in my case `B`), but from the class this method is being called (in my case `A`).

Comment: A subclass method will only be called if it overrides the above one. In your case, it doesnt override hence the call is not dispatched to the lower method